# If you don’t have the funds, you’re not going to complete the project successfully

Tags: articles

The [article](https://www.projectmanager.com/training/create-and-manage-project-budget) about managing project's budget begins with the following:

> If you don’t have **the funds**, you’re not going to complete **the project** successfully.

Why "the" is used in front of "funds" and in front of "project"? I'd write the sentence this way:

> If you don’t have **funds**, you’re not going to complete **a project** successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speaker refers to particular funds and to a particular project, and so both require definite articles. The sentence is a somewhat elliptic, so you can think of it like this:

> If you don’t have the funds ***(that you need to complete this project)***, you’re not going to complete the project ***(that we are doing now)*** successfully.

Your other sentence

> If you don’t have funds, you’re not going to complete a (you could also use ***any***) project successfully.

refers rather to a general state of facts: *Without money one can't do a project*.